# Unix equivalent of `du -sb` to get summarized size in bytes

Tags: osx, disk-usage, bsd, coreutils

On Linux using GNU `du` to calculate the size of directory recursively in bytes I can run:

```
du -sb /etc
```

What is equivalent syntax for BSD `du` based on the fact that `-b` parameter is not available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My 1st thought...

```
find $HOME | xargs stat -f%z | awk '{ s+=$1 } END { print s }'
```

...crawls thru `$HOME`, gets file sizes in bytes from `stat` and sums them up using `awk`.

Tested on NetBSD7.

Answer (score 2):

By default in BSD `du` the block counts will be displayed in 512-byte blocks, so the value can be multiplied. Here is example in bash:

```
echo $(($(du -s /etc | cut -f1) * 512))
```

The block size can be changed using `BLOCKSIZE`, but minimum blocksize is 512. Here is after change:

```
echo $(($(BLOCKSIZE=1024 du -s /etc | cut -f1) * 1024))
```